# Utilizar drag and drop para posicionar uma imagem

Tags: html, jquery, css

A minha duvida é a seguinte, eu tenho uma pagina de postagem de conteúdo e nessa pagina, ao final, tenho um campo de upload de foto para fazer parte do conteúdo... Mas o que eu queria é que o usuário posicionasse a foto de acordo com a necessidade dele, parecido com o Word... aí encontrei o DnD (Arrastar e soltar) do jquery, mas não sei se ele se aplicaria para posicionamento, pois não é possível subir imagem dentro do input para depois posiciona-lá arrastando... Existe algum modo para isso?

Answer (score 1):

Use um editor de textos [WYSIWYG](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) como o [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/full-featured/).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou ainda o [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

São os dois que geralmente utilizo.

Você não falou com que linguagem está inserindo essas informações no banco de dados, mas caso seja PHP há funções para a inserção considerando a formatação, partes em negrito, tabelas, paragráfos e outros recursos de organização textual.

Ainda, você pode selecionar os recursos quais deixará ativos. Por exemplo, só os textos e upload de imagens conforme vontade e necessidade do usuário.

Aqui neste próprio formulário de respostas há esse recurso.

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de citar a linguagem, mas sim, é PHP... Eu irei testar depois. Muito obrigado, não conhecia esses editores.

Comment: Se eu puder lhe auxiliar ainda, deixe nos comentários.